# How to display data from database in html via php in other language?

Tags: php

I have a problem with PHP. In database, the whole information is written in Armenian, and I want to get that data and display it on the screen using PHP and HTML. But when I write,

```
$conn = new mysqli("some-host", "some-username", "some-password", "some-website");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM categories";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Category: " . $row["category"]."<br>";
}
```

the output is:

```
id: 1 - Category: ????????? ?????????????
id: 2 - Category: ??????????? ?????????????
id: 3 - Category: ???
```

What I must to do to change "?" symbols into Armenian letters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Set charset as general utf-8

Answer (score 0):

mysql set charset

```
SET NAMES 'utf8'
SET CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Or

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: You can also use in the php code this: $conn->set_charset("utf8") if you want to make filters such as select * from table where field='armenian chars' . OR use mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");

Comment: He said that he initiates a `new mysqli` object, so i belive it will be ok.

Comment: dılo sürücü, your version didn't work. Error appers in phpmyadmin. But MihaiM's version did work. Thanks!